# gitorious fatal error when accessing remotely

Tags: bitnami, gitorious

I just installed a new gitorious server. From inside the LAN I'm able to pull\push without a problem. However from outside the LAN I get:

```
== Gitorious: ==========================================================
fatal error
========================================================================

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I found the following error in `gitorious_auth.log`:

```
FATAL -- : NoMethodError private method `gsub!' called for nil:NilClass: /opt/bitnami/apps/gitorious/htdocs/script/../lib/gitorious/ssh/client.rb:34:in `initialize'
```

What does it mean and how can I fix it? How come it occurs only from remote access?

Answer (score 0):

I now believe the root cause of the problem that I was using `:` instead of `/` in the url. For example I used:

```
git@[domain]:[proj]/[repo.git]
```

instead of:

```
git@[domain]/[proj]/[repo.git]
```

I'm not sure why this mattered while accessing remotely whereas it didn't when I was within the LAN...